# Paypal button generation in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, paypal

I have this script "Paypal button":

```
<script async="async" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=asdfsdaf@sda.ru" 
    data-button="buynow" 
    data-name="<?=php echo Yii::app()->user->id;?>" 
    data-quantity="1" 
    data-amount="3" 
    data-currency="USD" 
    data-shipping="0" 
    data-tax="0"
></script>
```

The database table "Payments" and the field "Content" where the HTML code that will be generated in the form. Button is displayed, but data-name: display "user->id.?>" but not the user id. Ie php is not interpreted. Prompt how to insert user name in this field in the form?

In the view, the data is displayed like this:

```
<?="<div>".$model->text."</div>"?>
```

Comment: Syntax error .. "<?=php echo" -> "<?php echo $model->id ?> !....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error!

```
<script async="async" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=asdfsdaf@sda.ru" 
    data-button="buynow" 
    data-name="<?php echo isset(Yii::app()->user->id) ? Yii::app()->user->id : '';?>" 
    data-quantity="1" 
    data-amount="3" 
    data-currency="USD" 
    data-shipping="0" 
    data-tax="0"
></script>
```